# persisted login with simpleJWT

Tags: django-rest-framework, django-rest-framework-simplejwt

So, I was checking how I can implement similar behavior in a Firebase application where the user does not have to enter his credentials every now and then. I found that they too use something like an access token and a refresh token. I generally have found that we should set the expiration time for the access token to be an hour at the most, and the refresh token to be a week at the most, but for Firebase their refresh token expires when the user's profile is deleted or disabled, or when we do it ourself. I think that isn't the best thing to do as it won't be secure, so, what should I do? Should I do something similar to what they are doing or should I use SlidingTokens in simpleJWT or maybe just set the expiration time for refresh tokens to be 3 months or something so that they have to login every 3 months?
[here is the link where they mentioned this](https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/admin/manage-sessions)